# Week-number in PHP, again

Tags: php, date, week-number

We are using the ISO 8601-standard to show week numbers here in Sweden. Most people seems to be confused about this standard that week 1 can be in the former year. I am aware of this.

I have different strange problem, every date on a Monday is showing wrong week number. As far as I know weeks should start on Mondays according to this standard and the PHP manual. Have I missed something obvious? I am using PHP5.3.3. Thanks in advance!

`$week = date('W', strtotime('2011-01-24'));
//gives $week = 03`

`$week = date('W', strtotime('2011-01-25'));
//gives $week = 04 correct!`

According to my calendar 2011-01-24 should be week 4

[image]

Comment: That calendar is showing January **2010**

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! It actually seems to be a bug in iStat Menus. The 24th of January 2011 is a Monday if you check your caledar. I wish there was some way to edit my question with a correct image!

Comment: I have edited the image for you.

Comment: Using the same example code on my `PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.7` offers the behaviour that you are expecting, so I am confused...

What `LC_TIME` locale setting are you using? It could indeed be related, even though I can't see why a week would start on a Tuesday in any locale.

It could also be a timezone issue. Your date of `2011-01-24` could be interpreted as the day before if your timezone offset is negative...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely a timezone issue.

Try again by explicitly setting the timezone offset:

```
$week = date('W', strtotime('2011-01-24T00:00:01+0200')); // 03 - incorrect behavior
$week = date('W', strtotime('2011-01-24T00:00:01+0000')); // 04 - correct behavior!
```